# Individual Update Employer address/profile informaiton

Tags: profile

Using profiles individuals are able to update their own information. However i need an individual to be able to update their employers information. What solutions are there using wordpress for this?

Answer (score 1):

for WP or Joomla i think the only in-built option is if your Contact has a Permissioned Relationship with their Employer then they should be able to view and edit some details about their Employer via their [Contact Dashboard](http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fuser).

But my quick test on demo (i guessed the url to get to the dashboard since i don't 'know' WP) doesn't show the permissioned Relationships I just created for 'demo, demo' on the Contact Dashboard, which I assumed (wrongly) was just a [setting](http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fpreferences%2Fdisplay&reset=1) but MyContacts/Organisation was checked - hmm .

So either there is another setting that I have forgotten, or this is something I didn't know was a limitation in WP, or something else ;-)

But try it on your local anyway.

Also worth nothing that you can provide 2nd degree permissions via a [setting](http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fmisc&reset=1) (which i do see on WP)

Comment: sorry that wasn't as helpful as i expected it to be